# How to get back GUI? I removed it accidentally

Tags: gui

I remove my GUI and I attempt a lot to fix that but when I want fix dependencies I got lots of errors.
please help me step by step to fix this:

```
apt install ubuntu-desktop

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the sltuation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gdm8 : Depends: gnome-shell (>= 3.19.92) but it is not installable
gir1.2-snapd-1 : Depends: libsnapd-glibl (= 1.58-0ubuntu0.20.04.0) but 1.60-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
gjs : Depends: libgjsog (>= 1.63.90) but it is not installable
gnome-session-bin : Depends: dbus-x11
gnome-settings-daemon : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-common (= 3.36.1-0ubuntu1.1) but 42.1-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
gnome-shell-extension-appindicator : Depends: gnome-shell (>= 3.33) but it is not installable
Depends: gnome-shell (< 3.37) but it is not installable
gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons : Depends: gnome-shell (>= 3.33) but it is not installable
gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock : Depends: gnome-shell (< 3.37) but it is not installable
Depends: gnome-shell (>= 3.35.90) but it is not installable
language-selector-gnome : Depends: language-selector-common (= 0.204.2) but 0.219.1 is to be installed
libcairo-gobject-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
Depends: libcairo-perl but it is not going to be installed
libglib-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
libgtk3-per1 : Depends: libglib-object-introspection-perl (>= 0.043) but it is not installable
1 ibpulse-mainloop-glib0 : Depends: Lbpulse0 (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13) but 1:15.99.1+dfss1-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
libsmbclient : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5 is to be installed
Depends: libubcliento (= 2:4.15.13+dfsg-Oubuntu0.20.04.7) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-Oubuntu1.5 is to be installed
software-properties-gtk : Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.99.9.12) but 0.99.22.8 is to be installed
Recommends: gnome-keyring but it is not installable
ubuntu-desktop : Depends: gnome-shell but It is not installable
Recommends: deja-dup but it 1s not installable
Recommends: gnome-calendar but it is not installable
Recommends: gnome-keyring but it is not installable
Recommends: gnome-todo but it ls not installable
Recommends: libreoffice-style-breeze but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: network-manager-pptp-gnome but it is not installable
Recommends: orca but it is not Installable
Recommends: seahorse but it is not installable
Recommends: shotwell but it is not installable
ubuntu-desktop-minimal : Depends: gnome-shell but It is not installable
Recommends: gnome-keyring but it is not installable
Recommends: network-manager-pptp-gnome but it is not lnstallable
Recommends: orca but It is not installable
Recommends: seahorse but it is not installable
ubuntu-session : Depends: gnome-shell (>= 3.36.0-2ubuntu1*) but 1t is not nstallable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Your output clearly shows that you have added a non-Ubuntu apt source that is trying to install packages that are incompatible with your system. Delete that non-Ubuntu apt source. If you don't know which source you added, then edit your question to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: Reinstall Ubuntu. That would be simpler. And don't please don't enter random commands from the internet unless you know how they work. If in doubt, ask a question in this site